# Cómo retornar NULL en los campos extra cuando el join devuelve mas de un resultado?

Tags: mysql, join, sql, modelorelacional

Tengo la siguiente base de datos

```
create database if not exists db_join;
use db_join;

create table r1(nombre varchar(20),apellido varchar(20));
create table r2(apellido varchar(20),sexo char(1));
create table r3(apellido varchar(20), email varchar(20));

insert into r1 values('Juan','Martinez'),('Rosa','Perez'),('Omar',NULL),('Maribel','Martinez');
insert into r2 values('Martinez','M'),('Perez','F');
insert into r3 values('Martinez','juan@hotmail.com'),('Perez','NULL');
```

Necesito hacer una consulta con joins que me permita seleccionar el nombre, sexo y el email de todas las personas. Hasta el momento tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT nombre,sexo,email FROM r1 LEFT JOIN r2 ON r1.apellido=r2.apellido LEFT JOIN r3 ON r1.apellido=r3.apellido;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que hay dos personas que se llaman Martinez y se relacionan cuando no debería ser así ya que son diferentes personas.

*No puedo crear campos nuevos en las tablas.

*No se pueden modificar los registros de la tabla.

*Puedo agregar llaves foráneas o primarias.

En el resultado de la consulta la fila de **Maribel** debería ser

**Maribel NULL NULL**

Comment: el join lo haces sobre nombre+apellido pero devolves en el select solo el apellido

Comment: a que te refieres a que solo tienes la posibilidad de agregar llaves foráneas o primarias.?... Es decir que si puedes creearlas o no?... si quieres asegurarte al 100 % de que la consulta es correcta deberías poner como bien dices un id ya que puede haber casos que incluso los nombres completos son iguales...

Comment: Me refiero a que no puedo hacer modificaciones a las tablas como agregar el campo id, o algún otro
Pero si es posible agregar llaves primarias o foráneas

Comment: si no se puede modificar las tablas entonces el problema a resolver es cómo transformar en null los resultados que tengan mas de un valor, el hecho de que dos personas con el mismo apellido se relacionen es normal por que en las otras tablas no hay nombre o id que los diferencie: vos sabes al ver la primer tabla que son diferentes, pero el join en las otras tablas no tiene forma de saberlo

Comment: /2 las llaves primarias o foráneas actúan sobre los campos definidos y para que funcione por lo general deben ser únicas, es decir podes definir una clave primaria nombre+apellido y usarla como foránea en otra tabla sólo si tenes los dos campos, en tu ejemplo sólo hay apellido en común.

Comment: /3 usando un nombre+apellido como clave primaria y foranea te trae otro problema: personas que son diferentes pero tienen el mismo nombre y apellido

Comment: El problema con que no tenga id ninguna tabla es que no puedes saber que fila de la tabla r2 corresponde a la de r1...es decir si tienes dos (martinez, m) como sabes a quien le pertenece ese registro de la tabla r1?

Comment: @stre_leon me da la sensación que la movida va por "descartar" los joins que no son concluyentes devolviendo null. es un ejercicio interesante

Comment: @aloMalbarez si tienes toda la razon, es lo mas confiable, si hay mas de un apellido igual regresar nulo como indicador de que hay un error

Comment: @aloMalbarez El problema /3 en este ejercicio que quiero hacer no aplicaría y podría ignorarlo

Comment: creo que la solución que te da @aloMalbarez es la mas acertada, regresar nulo en caso de dos apellidos si es que puedes descartar un nombre+apellido igual

Comment: bueno esperemos un valiente que proponga una solución, se puede probar sql online en http://sqlfiddle.com/ ( había un post con otros sitios para pruebas pero no lo encuentro )

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar la consulta está bien, lo que está mal, es como relacionas los datos, si te fijas bien en R1 juan y Maribel tiene el apellido Martínez y en R2 dicen que todos los que tengan el apellido Martínez serán sexo:M y correo juan

Ya que no puedes agregar campos se me ocurre lo siguiente, que en las tablas R2 y R3, en apellido guardes tanto el nombre como el apellido, te quedaria algo asi:

```
CREATE TABLE r1 (
  nombre varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  apellido varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE r2 (
  apellido varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  sexo char(1) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE r3 (
  apellido varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO r1 (nombre,apellido) VALUES ('Juan', 'Martinez'),('Rosa', 'Perez'),('Omar', NULL),('Maribel', 'Martinez');

INSERT INTO r2 (apellido,sexo) VALUES ('Juan Martinez', 'M'),('Rosa Perez', 'F');

INSERT INTO r3 (apellido,email) VALUES ('Juan Martinez', 'juan@hotmail.com'),('Rosa Perez', 'NULL');
```

Y la consulta para ligar las 3 seria:

```
SELECT r1.nombre, r1.apellido, r2.sexo, r3.email FROM r1
LEFT JOIN r2 ON r2.apellido = concat(r1.nombre,' ',r1.apellido)
LEFT JOIN r3 ON r3.apellido = r2.apellido
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]